# Mixed content warning for insecure resources from Odoo

Tags: caching, odoo, service-worker, mixed-content

I am running Odoo and would like to add some caching mechanism.

In order to do so, I simply added a service worker and the following rout:

workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute(
'/web/',
workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate(),

);

Unfortunately i now always receive the following error message:
"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://test.emanju.de/sw.js' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://test.emanju.de/web/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Obviously Odoo references to some insecure sources. Now I have the following questions:
1) How am I able to identify these sources (all of them)? Can I somehow scan the whole page?
2) Can I some how still run my service worker and just ignore the insecure files? Is the a way to still follow my goal without adjusting the existing application code and fixing all insecure files?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem: Loading PDF presentation in the eLearning module ("slides") would request the resource over http rather than https. What worked in my case:

- adding `proxy_mode = True` into the `[options]` section of `odoo.conf` (if you deployed using docker, put odoo.conf into `/etc/odoo/odoo.conf`, which in their `docker-compose.yml` example is a shared folder (`./config:/etc/odoo`)
- nginx config I'm using (I was missing the X-Forwarded-Host header):

```
location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8069;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_request_buffering off;
proxy_connect_timeout  36000s;
proxy_read_timeout  36000s;
proxy_send_timeout  36000s;
send_timeout  36000s;
client_max_body_size 10240m;
}
```

- when in developer mode, go to Settings -> Technical -> System Parameters, and make sure your `web.base.url` contains https:// (some people also add `web.base.url.freeze` set to True -- this doesn't seem to have an effect on my installation)

Restart nginx, restart odoo, and voila, PDFs in Slides are being requested over https://.

Answer (score 0):

(This is not specific to Workbox, as insecure, mixed content is an issue whenever you're using `https://`.)

There's some advice in this "[Preventing Mixed Content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content)" article about how to identify a full list of insecure resources that are being loaded.

As mentioned in that article, assuming that `https://` versions of each of the URLs being loaded exist, you can use the `Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests` response header when serving your HTML to tell the browser to [automatically swap-in `https://` URLs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content#upgrading_insecure_requests).

Service workers require secure origins, and secure origins can't load resources via `http://`.